# What does the syntax `default (dict) .Values.outer.inner` mean in a helm template?

Tags: templates, kubernetes-helm, sprig-template-functions

Given `values.yaml`:

```
outer:
  inner: 
    someKey: false
```

What does the following syntax in a helm template file mean?

```
  {{- if index (default (dict) .Values.outer.inner) "someKey" }}
  {{- .... }}
  {{- end }}
```

From context, I can infer what I think it's supposed to do:  check if the specified key exists at the specified location.

But where does the `default (dict)...` syntax come from? Sprig?  I can't find it documented in any of these places:

https://v2.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#template-functions-and-pipelines

https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions

http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/

http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/defaults.html

And what does it actually mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This particular code avoids a failure if the values `outer: {...}` doesn't contain an `inner` key within it.

`dict` is a [Sprig function](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) that creates a new dictionary.  It can be called with any (even) number of parameters; `(dict)` with no parameters creates an empty dictionary.

`default x y` is the same as `y | default x` and calls the [Sprig `default` function](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/defaults.html).

The important thing this is trying to protect against is if `.Values.outer` doesn't have an `inner` key within it.  If that happened, `.Values.outer.inner` would be `nil`, and `.Values.outer.inner.someKey` would produce an error; the `default dict` block replaces `nil` with an empty dictionary, which can be used with `index` and similar template code.

I'll often write similar template blocks one layer at a time:

```
{{- $outer := .Values.outer | default dict -}}
{{- $inner := $outer.inner | default dict -}}
{{- if $inner.someKey }}
...
{{- end }}
```